AMD Ryzen AI 9 HX 375 vs AMD Ryzen 9 9900X - what is better to choose?
I am choosing a processor between AMD Ryzen AI 9 HX 375 and AMD Ryzen 9 9900X, and I can't figure out which is better. Please help me choose! I play games a little, I mainly need it for work. Ryzen AI 9 from the new line with AI looks attractive, but what does AI give? I looked at comparisons, it loses - https://siliconcat.net/cpu/compare/amd-ryzen-ai-9-hx-375-vs-amd-ryzen-9-9900x. Please advise what is better to choose?
